# How to convert from ByteBuffer to Integer and String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, nio, bytebuffer

I converted an `int` to a byte array using ByteBuffer's  `putInt()` method. How do I do the opposite? So convert those bytes to an int?

Furthermore, I converted a string to an array of bytes using the String's `getBytes()` method. How do I convert it the other way round? The `bytesArray.getString()` does not return a readable string. I get things like `BF@DDAD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ByteBuffer.getInt` method, specifying the offset at which the integer occurs, to convert a series of bytes into an integer.  Alternatively, if you happen to know the byte ordering, you can use bitwise operators to explicitly reconstruct the 32-bit integer from its 8-bit octets.

To convert an array of bytes into a `String`, you can use the `String(byte[])` constructor to construct a new `String` out of the byte array.  For example:

```
byte[] bytes = /* ... get array of bytes ... */
String fromBytes = new String(bytes);
```

Comment: Just a note that it's a good idea to specify what encoding you want to use when creating a `String` from raw bytes.