# Reading a String from ByteBuffer without double buffering

Tags: java, optimization, nio, bytebuffer

Is there a way to construct a `String` from `ByteBuffer` without first reading contents from the buffer to a intermediate `byte[]` or `char[]`?

An API similar to the [string constructor that takes a byte[]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) strikes me as ideal:

```
public String(ByteBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Charset charset)
```

... but no such thing exists.

I've found [How to convert from ByteBuffer to Integer and String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395695/how-to-convert-from-bytebuffer-to-integer-and-string), but it uses an auxiliary array.

I the next best thing I've found so far is to project the byte buffer as a `CharBuffer` and call [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#toString%28%29). But that doesn't allow for compressing the strings with something like `UTF-8`.

Comment: Does your ByteBuffer support the array() method?

Comment: It's memory mapped, so I don't think so. But these are all intricacies I want whatever API I use to understand.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. You can get the backing byte array for a `ByteBuffer` using its `array` method. Apart from not wanting to rely on an internal implementation detail, what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Perception, `array` is an optional operation, and can throw `UnsupportedOperationException - If this buffer is not backed by an accessible array`. I imagine that exact thing would happen if the ByteBuffer is a 1 GB memory-mapped file.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga - you probably should have mentioned the specific byte buffer implementation you are working with, or that you are looking for a general purpose solution.

Comment: Byte-array backed `ByteBuffer`s are pretty pointless all around (why not just use `byte[]` then); so it is reasonable assumption that one may be using native buffer.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`CharsetDecoder.decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) and calling [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#toString%28%29) on the returned [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing.

A ByteBuffer does not contain characters. They have to be converted to characters before you can make a String out of them.

Also, a String has to be inside the JVM memory. A ByteBuffer may be mapped or direct, in both cases it is outside the JVM.

In order to move the data into the JVM and convert it to characters, you have to use an auxiliary array.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see why the String can't do that within a constructor. Why force an extra array copy in APIs intended for high performance?

Comment: There would be no performance benefit, only additional complexity in an API that is already quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.String is immutable and final, so there is ultimately no choice but to eventually provide data in a format it already accepts.  (Short of manipulating its internals with reflection of course....)

You could hide the ugliness behind an API that uses string builder or something, but there will at some point be two copies of the array in memory, one in the builder and one for the actual string.

Comment: In the Sun JDK 1.6.0_u34, for example, `java.lang.String` has a package private constructor as follows: `/* Package private constructor which shares value array for speed. */ 
    String(int offset, int count, char value[]) { ... }` Seems to me an API in `java.lang` can avoid the second array...

Comment: yes, so if you used reflection to override access to that constructor, you could do it, as I mentioned :)

Comment: LOL, nods. Reflection would defeat the purpose here. But package private means other classes in the same package can use the constructor without any tomfoolery. This API seems to have been left in explicitly for optimization. I was hoping they used the coolness afforded to them...

Comment: Well, if the actual question is just "Why didn't Sun do XYZ?" we can't really provide you with an authoritative answer unless an ex-Sun engineer happens to be reading.... :)

Answer (score 0):

`String` is made of `char`s, not `byte`s. You would need a **character set**, which you use to convert the bytes to characters, e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-5, ...

If you don't know the character set, you will not know **which character the bytes represent**.

Comment: I agree. But that is why my dream API takes a Charset... See my OP.